# Process videos on Azure VM

Tags: azure, ffmpeg

I am building an application that will process uploaded video. Each uploaded video will be trimmed into multiple shorter parts and all the cuts will be concatenated to create a highlight of the original file. All the processing is done with ffmpeg.

I am using Azure File Storage, to upload the videos and be able to access them via Samba layer.
I also have an Azure VM where I mounted the shared folders.

What is the best approach on the worker?

- Should I build a console app and run it as a windows server inside an azure VM ?
- Is there another way of doing things?

I am looking for a way that can be scaled up in production.

If there another way of doing everything I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want scaling then host it in your VM as a Windows Service is not the best solution. You can use Azure Batch for that. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/batch/

I also recommend a looking to Azure Media Services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/

Comment: I read about Azure Batch. At this moment I am going with the VM because the scale is not a problem. I will re investigate your proposal when I am going live with the application. Thanks for the answer.